# How can I break into my own Drupal site?

Tags: security

I was doing a [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module tutorial. Half way through it I decided to install the tutorial companion files and foolishly replaced my files. In the companions readme it says the admin login is username - admin and password - admin.

But it is not! Now i’m completely locked out. Can someone tell me how I might break in to my tutorial site? I have access to the DB via PHPMyAdmin.

I was thinking a MySQL update command to the password field for the admin. Can someone tell me what I could use to reset the admin password?

I changed the admin email address then requested a new password but it has not fired off an email. 
I believe the password encryption method is sha1().

Comment: One more suggestion, if you have a running drupal site, open its database (for ex. with PhpMyAdmin), open `users` table, copy admin's encrypted password, put it into yours.. this should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Linux:

1. Install [drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) if you haven't already
2. Go to /install_directory/sites/mysite
3. Type sudo drush uli
4. Copy the link to your browser

Drush is extremely useful for many things.  The above will log you in as user 1, after which you can reset your password in the usual way.

Comment: Or do what J. Reynolds suggests, quicker, easier, doesn't require command line access... but then you still won't have drush =)

Comment: there was an error in that it could not output the host name, it had http://default/user/etc....  so i just replaced defualt w/ hostname and it worked. thanks

Comment: It gets the host name from your settings file.  If you haven't set `$base_url` it will just give you the site folder name.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this post: [Resetting the administrator password with sql-query (Drupal 7)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428)

> When, in Drupal 7, the password for user 1 (the administrator) is lost
> and the email notification or drush methods don't work, it is possible
> to set the password via a database query.

I have done it in the past using a PHP script (it provides the link to that post in above post).

> The password reset method described below uses a PHP script that must
> be uploaded to the web server to reset the administrator password. The
> ability to upload a PHP file to the server where the site is hosted is
> required for successful execution of this method.

And it is always prudent to make a backup of the database before making any unconventional changes to it.

Comment: before doing any thing with database just take a backup of database.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game, but the simplest solution for me would be:

1. Go to the `user` database table
2. Change the email of the "admin" user (Remember to save the original email.)
3. Go to `yoursite.com/user/password` and reset your password.
4. Change the email back to the original one.